# html 5 mode remove hash in angularjs+nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

i am new in mean stack i want to remove the hash in URL of the browser.i successfully do this but when i refresh the page at that time 'Network error 404 not found' comes so please help me to solve this problem.

below i show the code of index.html file.

```
 <script>
  var base = document.createElement('base');
         base.href = 'http://localhost:3000/';
         document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(base);
       </script>
```

below is the code of the config.router.js

```
angular.module('app')
        .config(
                ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider','$locationProvider', 'MODULE_CONFIG',
                    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider, MODULE_CONFIG) {
                     $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
```

below is the code of the server.js file of the node.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var country = require('./routes/country');
var category = require('./routes/Category');
var attributes = require('./routes/Attribute');
var subscription = require('./routes/subscription');
var mall = require('./routes/mall');
var http = require('http');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var app = express();
//var cors = require('cors');
// view engine setup
//app.use(cors());
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../app'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {

  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  next();
});
app.use(cookieParser());
//app.use(bodyParser({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../app/')));
/*allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {


  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length');
  next();
};

app.use(allowCrossDomain);*/
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../app/')));
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/api/user', user);
app.use('/api/country', country);
app.use('/api/city', country);
app.use('/api/state', country);
app.use('/api/mall', mall);
app.use('/api/category', category);
app.use('/api/attributes', attributes);
app.use('/api/subscription', subscription);
app.set('port',3000);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://52.39.244.83    /deals');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error',erroroccured);
db.once('open',startserver);
function erroroccured(){
    console.log('error');

}
function startserver(){
//  mongoose.set( "debug", true );
    var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
        console.log('Server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
    });
}

module.exports = app;
```

so please help me to come out from this problem thanks to all in advance.

Comment: refer to [this - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode).    A rewrite for ExpessJS routes is required in your case.

Comment: thanks to all of you i found the solution so many thanks for suggestion its a problem of rewrite inside express js not at angularside.its ok in angular side.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have defined the `hashPrefix('!')` config, your URLs will now be

```
index.html#!/path
```

If you want a plain HTML5 mode style, like

```
index.html/path
```

Just don't define the `hashPrefix`. It defaults to `''`.

Additionally you can also get rid of the base tag, but that might create issues with are going to define a base tag, define it as

```
  <head>
    <base href="/">
  </head>
```

Instead of `localhost:3000` as this would fail on your server.

Answer (score 0):

I think just use this should be fine

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

And in html

```
<head>
  <base href="/">
</head>
```